# Angular : After data binding component variable going out of scope

Tags: angular

I am facing a strange issue. Refer the following code.

// Variables at page level

```
nonAuthorizedResponse: INonAuthorizedResponse;
authorizedResponse: IAuthorizedResponse;
borrowersNonAuthorized: IBorrower[];
borrowersNonAuthsFiltered: IBorrower[];
authorizedData: IAuthorizedData[];

ngOnInit() {
// Get Data From Server
this.getDataFromServer();

//Setting Paging Data Source
this.setPagingSourceAfterDataLoad();
}
```

Following is the call to server:-

```
getDataFromServer(){
    this.nregMainPageHttpService.getBorrowListForMyActiveProfiles().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.nonAuthorizedResponse = data;
        this.borrowersNonAuthorized = this.nonAuthorizedResponse.borrowers;
        this.totalRecords = this.nonAuthorizedResponse.totalRecords;
      },
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error, () => { }
    );
 }
```

Following is the method:-

```
setPagingSourceAfterDataLoad(){
// this.borrowersNonAuthorized is showing undefined on debugging
if (this.borrowersNonAuthorized && this.borrowersNonAuthorized.length > 0) {
  this.nregMainPageBusinessLogicService.setPagingSourceProperties(this.totalRecords, this.pagingSourceForBorrowLevel);
}
}
```

The 2nd call is got paging component. This call is after `getDataFromServer()`;

Modified version:-

```
ngOnInit() {
// Get Data From Server
this.getDataFromServer();

// code commented moved inside getDataFromServer()
//this.setPagingSourceAfterDataLoad();
}

getDataFromServer(){
    this.nregMainPageHttpService.getBorrowListForMyActiveProfiles().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.nonAuthorizedResponse = data;
        this.borrowersNonAuthorized = this.nonAuthorizedResponse.borrowers;
        this.totalRecords = this.nonAuthorizedResponse.totalRecords;
        // call added
        this.setPagingSourceAfterDataLoad();
      },
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error, () => { }
    );
 }
```

Now the paging component works.

I fail to understand the issue why variable this.borrowersNonAuthorized becomes "undefined"

best regards,
Sidd

Comment: I'm guess you're using typescript but untyped.  The error is pretty clear.  Define a variable `mycollection`.  Don't expect people to guess what wrong because you wrote a comment explaining what you do post the code related

Comment: myCollection is a typed collection. I have not added the complete code.

Comment: Following is a better explanation:-

Comment: what `ngOnInt` do you mean `ngOnInit`? myCollection is undefined, probably because you're checking myCollection before your server hits the callback to the data

Comment: check the image for the code snippet, please.

Comment: I could not format the code and it took lots of time.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't `this.getDataFromServer()` an `async` operation? As johnny mention in his comment, your method `this.setPagingSourceAfterDataLoad()` is being hit before the server callback and populate your data...

To fix it, you will have to `await` the server call to finish.

Assuming you are using Angular HttpClient to make server call, you will have to either use `.toPromise()` or subscribe to the callback.

something like the following:

1) If `getDataFromServer` returns a promise

```
this.getDataFromServer().then(() => {
    this.setPagingSourceAfterDataLoad();
}
```

2) If `getDataFromServer` returns an observable

```
this.sub = this.getDataFromServer().subscribe(() => {
    this.setPagingSourceAfterDataLoad();
}
```

UPDATE: 
As suggested in the comment below, when one Server call is dependent on another, You should chain them together. The modified works because you are calling `setPagingSourceAfterDataLoad` within you subscription of `getDataFromServer`.

As for why you have undefined in your `borrowersNonAuthorized` I would debug you code and make sure data has a property `borrower`, my guess is that it is not defined.

Although the example above works, it is flawed as it will introduce **memory leak**. You need to hold a reference to your subscription and unsubscribe when you are done. If you do not unsubscribe, *each subscription will continue watching for changes*.

Base on the above code, i suggest the following small modification.

```
ngOnInit() {
    // Get Data From Server
    this.sub = this.getDataFromServer();
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
}

getDataFromServer(){
    return this.nregMainPageHttpService.getBorrowListForMyActiveProfiles().subscribe(
  data => {
    this.nonAuthorizedResponse = data;
    this.borrowersNonAuthorized = this.nonAuthorizedResponse.borrowers;
    this.totalRecords = this.nonAuthorizedResponse.totalRecords;
    // call added
    this.setPagingSourceAfterDataLoad();
  },
  error => this.errorMessage = <any>error, () => { }
  );
}
```

Comment: I have subscribe, the call. Please check the server side method in the code snippet. getDataFromServer method returns an observable.

Comment: i don't think you include the `getDataFromServer` snippet anywhere?

Comment: I have added the code in txt form. Please have a look.

Comment: Hey I saw your updated code, as your snippet show, your async call is dependent on one another, If you separate them, they will won't await one to finish before starting another. To fix that you will have to chain them together

Comment: Also keep in mind that when you create a subscription, you also need to unsubscribe, otherwise you will introduce memory leak in your web app.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of it. I need to add the same in the code.